# How to add data in existing XML file in C#?

Tags: c#, xml

I have a large xml file that I need to open and needs to add `<employee>` node inside the `<employees>` node in the existing file.

Below is the format of my xml.

```
<company> 
    <employees> 
        <employee> 
            <id>1</id> 
            <name>sa</name> 
        </employee> 
        <employee> 
            <id>2</id> 
            <name>sa</name> 
        </employee> 
        <employee> 
            <id>3</id> 
            <name>sa</name> 
        </employee> 
        <employee> 
            <id>4</id> 
            <name>sa</name> 
        </employee> 
    </employees> 
</company>
```

Can someone help me how I can add the data into existing xml file without using `XDocument` or `XmlDocument`. 
**Main reason behind this is file size is too large and I am not suppose to load the complete file into memory and do the further processing.**

Comment: Why "without using XDocument"?

Comment: My xml file contains large number of data. It may contain records in Lakhs also. That is why I don't want to use XmlDocument. It may cause the performance degradation.

Comment: You said `XDocument`, not `XmlDocument`. Or don't you want you use that either?

Comment: Have you tried using either XDocument or XmlDocument to see if the performance hit of using either is even noticeable?

Comment: I suggest you start here [Efficient Techniques for Modifying Large XML Files (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302289.aspx).

Comment: I believe it's possible to chain an `XmlReader` to an `XmlWriter` and process the file as it's being read. Oh, I'm too slow. See the MSDN document provided by @WimOmbelets

Comment: @WimOmbelets thanks for the suggestion. I will check this link.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Employee
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;



    public void EmployeeXMLs()
    {
        var Employees = new[] { new Employee
                                    {Name="Rajat Jaiswal",
                           Id = 101
                           },
                   new Employee      {Name="Sharad Jaiswal",
                           Id = 102
                           },
                  };

        XElement contacts = new XElement("employees",
                    from p in Employees
                    select new XElement("employee",
                        new XElement("Id", p.Id),
                        new XElement("Name",p.Name)

                    )
                );
        Console.WriteLine(contacts);

    }
}
```

Comment: OP wants to avoid reading a large XML file into memory. Your `xDoc`is an `XDocument`that has parsed the file and thus places it in its entirety in memory.

Comment: Your edit now doesn't read the existing XML file at all... Please read the OP's question and the comments to it again

Comment: @Rajat Jaiswal: I have to add some data into my existing file without loading the complete file into memory.